# SharePoint security trimming control on masterpage doesnot hide the div completely for subsites if MDS is turned ON

Tags: security-trimming, mds

We are using SharePoint security trimmed control. This control surrounds the `'<div id="s4-ribbonrow">'`

Only users with 'edit items' permissions are able to see the ribbon.

However, suppose a user with only read permission logs in then he cannot see the ribbon div. But if he goes to a subsite then he can see the white color of the div (not contents).

I turn MDS off and then this white div disappears.

Whats going on?

Comment: Isn't there a "Delta" control (Control named DeltaSomething" somewhere near the ribbonrow in the master page? Try moving your security trimming outside of this delta.

Comment: The trim control is placed above <div id="s4-ribbonrow"> which is between the end of one AjaxDelta and before the start of another AjaxDelta

Comment: So add it outside of the delta it is now inside of.

Comment: I have mentioned it is between end of a delta and start of another delta. That means it is outside.